# Equivalent of isnumeric(X) & ~isnan(X)?

Tags: matlab

I find myself writing stuff like this a lot:

```
if isnumeric(X) & ~isnan(X)
   % etc etc
end
```

Before I clutter the namespace with my own test

```
function out = isanumber(X)
    out = isnumeric(X) & ~isnan(X);
end
```

does MATLAB already have an equivalent test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't.

`NaN` is of a numeric class (`double` by default, conforming to IEEE754), which makes `isnumeric` evaluate to `true` when passed the `NaN`. I'll immediately admit that the seemingly trivial

```
isnumeric ( not a number )
```

actually gives *true* is somewhat counter-intuitive, but it makes perfect sense when you're reading large amounts of data from a file for instance, and some elements of the matrices read thusly are `NaN` (missing, misconverted or similar) -- in such cases, it would be *pretty darn annoying* if `isnumeric(NaN)` would then say `false`.

So as usual, it all depends on how you look at it. The MathWorks decided (quite possibly after a lot of research) that the cases in which it makes sense to return `true` are far more numerous than the opposite. So, you'll have to always manually test *both* cases I'm afraid.

By the way, you wouldn't be cluttering so much if you just make it a sub- or nested function:

```
% All in the same file: 

function varargout = main(varargin)

    % Delegate checking, parsing, etc. the input arguments 
    % to a subfunction
    [varargin{1:nargin}] = parseInputArguments(varargin{:});


    % ...So you can just go on and do all your main stuff here
    % without all the usual clutter of parsing the arguments


end


% Main's argument parser
function varargout = parseInputArguments(varargin)

    % ...parse all sorts of stuff here

    % the readable test:
    if isanumber(varargin{2})
        varargout{2} = rand(5); end

    % ...parse more stuff here


    % nested helper function to aid readibility without 
    % polluting the main function namespace too much
    function yn = isanumber(x)
        yn = isnumeric(x) & ~isnan(x);
    end

end
```

Comment: I believe that you have a typo with your short-circuiting `&&`. Your `isanumber` function will only work for scalars -this is Matlab after all.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely you want [`isfinite(X)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfinite.html).

Admittedly it isn't exactly equivalent to `isnumeric(X) & ~isnan(X)`, it's equivalent to `isnumeric(X) & ~isnan(X) & ~isinf(X)`, but I'm guessing you don't want the other special cases (plus and minus infinity) either.

Comment: `isfinite(X)` by itself isn't equivalent to `isnumeric(X) & ~isnan(X) & ~isfinite(X)`. `isnumeric` filters out anything that is not a numeric datatype, but `isfinite('a')` and `isfinite(false)` both return `true` for non-numeric arguments.

Comment: @horchler: You mean `isnumeric` doesn't?  I guess I'm too accustomed to C++, where char and bool are considered primitive integral types

Comment: don't you mean : isnumeric(X) & ~isnan(X) & ~isinf(X) ? otherwise you have a endless loop if isfinite is calling itself.